# Deleting files with wildcard in updater-script

Tags: android, edify

I can use delete of updater-script to delete a file in /system:

```
delete("/system/app/YouTube.apk");
```

However, I can't do the following

```
delete("/system/app/*.odex");
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Note to people attempting to use a wildcard to remove every file inside a directory: you can use the delete_recursive command to delete a directory and everything in it. As @raulx222 states, the commands are limited, I don't think you can filter this one by file type either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the commands are limited..and you only can delete a file if you specify its full name and path.
However you can write a sh script to do that thing, and execute it from updater-script.

For example create a sh file with the following code and place it in root of your zip:

```
#!/sbin/sh

rm -rf /system/app/*.odex
```

And execute it from updater-script

```
package_extract_file("rmodex.sh", "/tmp/rmodex.sh");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/rmodex.sh");
run_program("/tmp/rmodex.sh", "");
delete("/tmp/rmodex.sh");
```

Where rmodex.sh is the file which you made.
And one more thing, be careful because `rm -rf /system/app/*.odex` will also remove all folders with *.odex name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this solution on my next updater-script.